# C++ seg fault when printing a vector<int> element from a member function

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a class with an int vector data member. I initialize the vector to 26 elements, all with value -99 in the constructor. I can cout element 0 in the constructor and it prints "-99". The constructor then calls another member function that doesn't modify the vector but when I try to cout element 0 from that function I get a segmentation fault. Below I've posted screenshots of the relevant parts of the header and the two member functions. To be specific the code works as posted but if I move line 26 to line 46 I get the seg fault. Any helpful suggestions? Thank you!

header file:

```
class Seq
{
private:
    vector<int> assignments;
    string original;
    vector<Expression> sequence;
    bool valid;

public:

    void print_assignments();
    Seq();
    Seq(const string& s);
    void parse(const string s, int);
    vector<Expression> get_sequence();
    void display_sequence();
    void evaluate();
```

Constructior and the member function (parse) it calls. Moving the first cout statement the line below the second cout statement causes the fault.

```
Seq::Seq(const string& s)
{
    original = s;
    vector<int> assignments(26, -99);
    parse(s, s.size());
    cout << assignments[0] << endl;
}

void Seq::parse(const string s, int length)
{
    Expression e;
    string temp1, temp2;
    int i = 0;
    while((s[i] != ';')&&(i < length))
    {
        i++;
    }
    if(i>0)
    {
        temp1 = s.substr(0, i);
        e.set(temp1);
        sequence.push_back(e);
        if(sequence.back().get_type() == 0)
        {
            cout << sequence.back().get_token(0).get_token()[0] << endl;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code **in the question**, not on an external link, *especially* not an image.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to fix it

Comment: ^---- And not all the code nor some arbitrary snippet, but a [mcve] please!

Comment: Sorry to be so harsh, but the more care you put into your question the more people will care to answer. You get out what you put in.

Comment: This is the last website where people will click on random links

Comment: Sorry, I don't post that often but I try to be polite and direct and responsive. I posted the pics because then I could reference the lines I was trying to swap. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a local vector named "assignments" in the constructor which is shadowing the data member with the same name, so the data member "assignments" probably still has zero length, hence the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while((s[i] != ';')&&(i < length))
```

to

```
while(i < length && s[i] != ';')
```

In your version, if `s` is empty or `i` is already greater than `length`, you'll get an AV or a segfault.

Also, stop naming variables `temp`.

Comment: I didn't know I could list multiple conditions in that format! That'll clean up lots of my code, thank you!